# Why screen shows black preview in Video View for android lollipop version?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-videoview

I am using `k4l-video-trimmer` lib for video trimming. Whenever I'm loading video in `Lollipop` version device that time goes black, and no preview will display on screen. And there is no proper thumbnail of video.
[video preview is not shown as per video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGoAc.png)

Comment: are you saying the app is running well on older version of OS? If so, can you check if you have the required permission

Comment: Can you provide some source code?

Comment: remember after Marshmallow , your app need to acquire permission only when your app needs it. No longer can declare on manifest.